# jquery.easing.min.js is vulnerable how to update latest version?

Tags: jquery

I've downloaded the JS using this link: `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js` but it is showing as vulnerable so how/from where can I update it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the latest jquery.easing.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js now its working fine. :)